# Сказуемое в односоставном предложении

Tags: сказуемые

Какое сказуемое будет в предложениях типа "Отец на работе."?

Answer (score 4):

Владимир, Ваши доводы имеют смысл, некоторые учёные тоже пытались настаивать на том, что в таких предложениях сказуемым становится остаток от состава сказуемого(обстоятельство или дополнение), перетягивая на себя лексическое значение, но потом попадали в тупик, запутываясь в дебрях синтаксиса предложения.

Вот Вы же тоже не решили ещё, двусоставное оно или односоставное(у Вас в названии сказуемое односоставного предложения)Как оно может быть односоставным при подлежащем и **составе** сказуемого?

Сейчас превалирует мнение, что это в любом случае ДВУсоставное предложение, а вот полное или неполное - споры есть. Кто говорит, что неполное, потому что пропущено сказуемое, кто-то - что полное, потому что оно и не нужно, без него предложение самодостаточно. Но ведь это разницы нет - одно словоблудие.Есть грамотное название - эллипсис - "опущение".Это как вечный спор про курицу и яйцо - что от чего произошло.

Эллиптическими предложениями со значением бытия мы вслед за Н.С. Валгиной называем самостоятельно употребляемые двусоставные предложения особого типа, спецификой структуры которых является сказуемое, выраженное нулевым бытийным глаголом, причем не упомянутое в контексте или не связанное с ситуацией, то есть в смысловом отношении не являющееся необходимым для передачи данного соо6щения. Например: Под горою темный вход. ( Пушкин); Пред ним живая голова.

```
   Второстепенные члены предложения можно убрать без потери 
   основной мысли высказывания. убираем: Отец находится. - 
   смысл сохранился? Он (отец) терялся?
```

Находится-теряется -это уже каламбур на основе многозначности. Вы просто упрямитесь и не хотите согласиться, что обстоятельство места уже указывает на БЫТИЕ, существование предмета в пространстве и времени, остальное неважно - он есть на работе, а какое действие производит - строгает, пилит, рисует,сейчас неважно, важно, что он там находится. Если же "на работе" считать сказуемым, каков его вид? Составное именное? Но к составному именному два вопроса: он каков? и он есть что?- не подходит. Глагольное тоже отпадает, нет там глагола.

Не всё так однозначно, не всегда можно убрать второстепенные члены,бывает предложение вообще без главных членов:Вот диалогическая речь:

-Чего не пробовали - удить или любить?

-Первое.

Это же дополнение? Давайте уберём. Ничего не осталось, но и к подлежащему и сказуемому его не отнесёшь. Так что ничего не нужно убирать, просто задайте вопрос, как предлагает Серж:

Отец есть кто?-рабочий-сказуемое. Отец где?-на работе-обстоятельство, указывающее, на присутствие сказуемого бытийного значения.Кстати, тоже эллипсис, на и так понятно, что спрашивается про нахождение отца, а не про то, что он **делает**

Comment: Спасибо. Понятно, что на эту тему ещё будут исследования и, возможно, открытия. В элементарных частицах ещё тоже не до конца разобрались...

Comment: Возможно. Может, назовут по-другому.

Answer (score 1):

> Какое сказуемое будет в предложениях типа "Отец на работе"?

Сказуемого здесь нет. ***Отец*** -- подлежащее, ***на работе*** -- обстоятельство места. Предложение семантически полное, но структурно неполное. Такие предложения называются ***эллиптическими***.

Присутствие в таких предложениях "следов" сказуемого в виде приглагольных распространителей (дополнений и обстоятельств) позволяет некоторым исследователям говорить о наличии в них ***"нулевого сказуемого".***

Именно так характеризуются подобные предложения в учебниках  Бабайцевой, Кустовой…

===

Имеет место и другой взгляд на предложения типа "Отец на работе". См. [**Грамматику-80**](http://rusgram.narod.ru/2372-2404.html):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> **§ 2372.** В двукомпонентных подлежащно-сказуемостных предложениях, строящихся по схеме N1 - N2 (Adv), подлежащим является имя в форме
>   им. п., а сказуемым - имя в форме любого косвенного падежа,
>   обстоятельственное наречие... Сказуемое может быть выражено одной из
>   следующих грамматических форм.
>
> <...>
>
> II. **В сказуемом - падежная форма имени с предлогом.** Здесь возможны
>   самые разные формы. Признак конкретизируется как одно из следующих
>   значений.
>
> <...>
>
> 2) Характеристика по месту, пространственной отнесенности...
>   **Предл. п.**: *Приказ - на доске; Поворот - в двадцати шагах; Корабль - в море; Час тоски невыразимой!.. Все во мне и я во всем! (Тютч.); **Теркин снова на войне** (Твард.); Не знаю, кто это оказывается в кабаках: берлинцы вечером дома (Шкл.).*

Comment: Нулевое сказуемое - "быть" в наст. вр. Здесь может подразумеваться пропущенное сказуемое "находится". Но "Отец находится." - не очень осмысленно, Без слов "на работе" предложение вообще теряет первоначальный смысл. Это не очень похоже на обычное обстоятельство.

Comment: _**Владимир:** Это не очень похоже на обычное обстоятельство._ === Но какой-то вопрос к словам "на работе" Вы же можете поставить? Думаю, наиболее естественным будет такой: _"**Где** находится отец?" -- "На работе"_.  А  какие члены предложения отвечают на вопрос "где?", кроме как не обстоятельства места?

Comment: Владимир, действительно, в таких предложениях обычно говорят о нулевом сказуемом, т.к. само сказуемое формально не представлено. Оно и не нужно в предложении, потому в смысловом отношении не является необходимым. Хотя и участвует в формировании этих предложений.

Comment: Основа предложения самодостаточна, т. е. составляет законченное в смысловом плане предложение. Уберём второстепенные члены из предложения "Отец на работе." - Отец. Это предложение уже говорит о факте существования отца, смысл предложения совсем другой.

Comment: И почему тогда в предложении "Отец - рабочий" или "Отец был рабочим" сказуемое - рабочий, был рабочим. Можно же спросить: отец был КЕМ? - дополнение?

Comment: Владимир, что вы хотите этим сказать ''Основа предложения самодостаточна, т. е. составляет законченное в смысловом плане предложение''.? В этом предложении в смысловом плане излишен, ни играет роли. Поэтому опущен. Вмысл этого предложения не том, что есть отец, а в том, что он  - на работе.

Comment: Смысл эллиптических предложений заключаетя в том, чтобы сообщить о месте, времени, способе характеризующее действие или состояние, или указать на объект действия, направление действия: ***На синем, ослепительно синем небе — полыхающее огнем июльское***

Comment: А если смысл предложения в том, что отец на работе, то не является ли это сказуемым? Я знаю теорию про эллиптические предложения и то, что  такие предложения некоторые считают неполными с обстоятельством места или времени. НО логически понять не могу. Почему "на работе" не входит в сказуемое, если в этом и есть смысл предложения?

Comment: В предложении ''Отец - рабочий" - составное именное сказуемое.  Значение которого сообщить о реалии, названной в подлежащем).

Comment: На работе - второстепенный член предложения - обстоятельство.Сказуемое не представлено, но мыслится, подразумевается. В данном случае это сказуемое ''находится". Ср.: ***Отец находится на работе***.

Comment: Второстепенные члены предложения можно убрать без потери основной мысли высказывания. убираем: Отец находится. - смысл сохранился? Он (отец) терялся?

Answer (score 0):

Спор пустяковый.
Поставьте в прошедшее или будущее время.

Отец был на работе. Синтаксис предложений тождественен. Что здесь "был" если не сказуемое?
Отсюда имеем, что "нуль-сказуемое" в принципе ничем от обычного сказуемого не отличается. Предложение полное и двусоставное. А хотя бы и односоставное. Суть не изменится, спор чисто терминологический.